# Header files can run in main class. How is that possible?

Tags: c++, c, header

When I working with C programming it's normal `include` method is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

`Output: Hello World`

Now I have tried to put my `#include` into my main class and its run perfectly **without any errors or warnings.**

```
int main()
{
    #include <stdio.h>
    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

`Output: Hello World`

I have tried this method with `C++`. I couldn't do that kind of activity in there it gives me lot of errors.

Why only `C` have this technique?
How is that possible?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Aside from unusual, what do you think is wrong with that?

Comment: I have tried to put `#include <iostream>` into main class in `C++`, but it gives me lot of errors. There for I wonder how is this possible in `C`.

Comment: C and C++ different languages, why expect same? Again - What in an include file do you expect that is illegal inside a C function?

Comment: `stdio.h` contains code that is only turned on for `C++` and that code cannot be placed where you have the `#include`. Why would you want to do something like that anyway?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` exist in it's pure format in main class even without `;` or etc. It behave like a comment but compiling. And also it didn't give any warnings. That's the reason I thought how is that legal.

Comment: What does that mean? `#include` essentially pastes the contents of the whole file into that location. So it's nothing like a comment.

Comment: @Kalana The preprocessor is the same for both C and C++. As a follow up to your exercise, you could run the preprocessor alone and see how the code looks like. Maybe that would clear things out for you on why the C++ compiler complains about it and the C one doesn't

Comment: I know it is not a comment it compiles without any warnings. That's my point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/misc/sys/cdefs.h.html#117) ,inside `cdefs.h` `__BEGIN_DECLS` is defined as

```
#ifdef        __cplusplus
#define __BEGIN_DECLS        extern "C" {
#define __END_DECLS        }
#else
#define __BEGIN_DECLS
#define __END_DECLS
#endif
```

This `__BEGIN_DECLS` is used in `stdio.h` as seen [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/stdio.h.html)

For `C++`, `__BEGIN_DECLS` expands to `extern "C"` and linkage specification should be at global scope not inside `main`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you for your explain and valuable site link. I wonder why do they remove that facility in `C++`? I think they tried to save our time :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have a lot of curiosity.

I only have an idea about `C` relative question

First of all, you need to understand the `compile process`

Briefly, there are 4 major (I call them helper) helper in the `compile process`

In your code `#include<stdio.h>` located in the main function works well because of the first guy named `Preprocessor`.

`Preprocessor` usually replaces or makes other helpers know the location of your `function` or `variables`

For example,

`#define TRUE         1`

If you define `TRUE` as `1` in your code, preprocessor replaces all `TRUE` as `1`

As we know, the location of `printf()` is in the `<stdio.h>`.

If you want to understand specifically, then run `gcc -E main.c` in your terminal.
I advise you not to put `#include<stdio.h>` after `printf()`

Answer (score 2):

The c++ headers (as opposed to c headers) define namespaces (std, etc.) which would trigger an error if included in the body of any function (a namespace definition must appear either at file scope or immediately within another namespace definition).